# Symfony form with multiple files

Tags: php, symfony, fine-uploader, oneupuploaderbundle

I'm using Symfony 3.1 trying to attach multiple files to a form.

So far I can upload files, create an entity and store in database for each one. Using OneupUploaderBundle with FineUploader.

The problem is those file are not attached with the rest of my form data.

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Oneup\UploaderBundle\Event\PostPersistEvent;
use AppBundle\Entity\AppointmentFile;

class AppointmentUploadListener
{
    protected $manager;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $manager)
    {
        $this->manager = $manager;
    }

    public function onUpload(PostPersistEvent $event)
    {
        dump($event);
        die();
        $file = $event->getFile();

        $object = new AppointmentFile();
        $object->setFilename($file->getPathName());

        $this->manager->persist($object);
        $this->manager->flush();
    }
}
```

I tried adding my form serialized to the upload parameters, but if I've 3 files, it would upload my form data 3 times.

```
var uploader = new qq.FineUploader({
    element: document.getElementById('fine-uploader'),
    debug: true,
    form: 'newAppointmentForm',

    request: {
        endpoint: "{{ oneup_uploader_endpoint('appointment') }}",
        params: {
            appointment: $('#newAppointmentForm').serialize()
        },
    }
});
```

The main purpose is to store an Appointment with attached files. The entities are therefore Appointment (columns: appointment data and arraycollection of files) and AppointmentFile (columns: id, filename, and mime/type).

Any advise is welcome.

Comment: Could you post your entity relationships?? Probably you will have to set the relations manually. Like $object->addFile($file1); $file1->setAppointment($object);   $object->addFile($file2); $file2->setAppointment($object)

Comment: "if I've 3 files, it would upload my form data 3 times." Why is this a problem? The files will consume the vast majority of resources. And if it didn't behave this way, which request should contain your form data? (keeping in mind that Fine Uploader sends a unique request for each file)

Comment: @RayNicholus if that's the supposed way to work my problem is with the service logic, how could I detect when the last file is send to insert the form data only once?

Comment: http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/events.html#allComplete